# facebook like results to page 403

Tags: facebook, joomla, facebook-like

If i like a page on my website. It is posted to facebook. The problem is when a second user clicks the like on facebook. They are taken to a 403 forbidden page.

likes on http://www.cmypictures.com/photos/index.html
result to

http://www.cmypictures.com/photos/index.html?fb_action_ids=10151367960904866&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=timeline_og&action_object_map=%7B%2210151367960904866%22%3A10150286116634264%7D&action_type_map=%7B%2210151367960904866%22%3A%22og.likes%22%7D&action_ref_map=%5B%5D

i have noted that if i manually delete `%3A"og.likes"%7D&action_ref_map=%5B%5D` at the end of the link, the desired page is opened.

Why is facebook adding this code at the end and what can be done to avoid this? Just to mention I run my website on joomla.

Please help

Comment: This is a problem with your site, your (or the joomla) developers need to not return a 403 error when the facebook referral params are present

Answer (score 1):

Facebook adds this for referral purposes so you can see the data in /analytics. As mentioned by @igy you need to check your CMS as it is not handling the params properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I contacted my hosting provider and submitted a ticket, I have no idea what they did to fix this but it was sorted out pretty quickly. Something in the link may have been blacklisted or some combination of the '.' and the lenght of the link might have caused the issue. Contact your hosting provider for a solution.

Comment: This isn't a hosting provider problem.  Unless you also pay them to manage your website they probably won't help.